# What does the obscure javascript error b(e.target).zIndex is not a function mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery

To give more information I am using the modular form here:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form

```
`b(e.target).zIndex` is not a function  
[Break on this error] `(function(a){a.widget("ui.mouse",{opti...is._unrotate}return this}})})(jQuery);`  
/js/jquery-ui.min.js
```

I also seem to be getting the error "Too much recursion"

```
too much recursion  
[Break on this error] `3||a.nodeType===8)){if(a.setInterval&&...this.special[o]||{};if(!t){t=e[o]={};`  
https://my.dev.peer1.com/js/jquery/jquery-1.4.min.js
```

I know its not much to go on but I was hoping someone might have experience with similar issues.

Comment: When developing, use the non-minified versions, then the errors aren't obscure and you get the useful variable names, etc.  You can see here, google hosts the minified and non-minified: http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/documentation/index.html#jquery Non for development, minified for production, life easier :)

Comment: You have not provided enough information to receive an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when your browser detects a deadlock and kills javascript from an infinite loop, specifically an infinite recursive loop.  *Something* you are doing is causing jQuery to loop and recurse (call the same function hierarchy over and over) in a way it can't escape.

The error here is likely outside of jQuery: the way you're *calling* jQuery to do something.  To give more details and resolve this, you'd need to post the code you're running that throws this error.

As I mentioned in comments (in case it gets more eyes here later)  You should use the uncompressed (non-minified) version of jQuery (or any javascript really) for development, and minified for production.  This results in much easier to read, debug, and/or google-able errors.  You can always get the uncompressed and minified versions [here at jQuery's download page](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery).

Answer (score 0):

I would also like to add to this. I've googled for a solution for this but the answer/solution checked wasn't the reason why I got the error.  But a coworker helped me out.

I got the same error and it's because of the `model: true` option.

Here's my snippet of code I ended up commenting out the `modal:true`:

```
jQuery( "#dialog-delete-warning" ).dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height:140,
    /*
    modal: true,
        */
    buttons: {
        Cancel: function() {
            jQuery( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
        "Ok": function() {
            jQuery( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with 'jQuery errors' like this is that they are normally caused elsewhere, the solution is seldom obvious. I had a similar error which happened when I tried to drag a modal dialog. Using both the latest version of jQuery and jQuery UI has solved it.